# SpriteKit Obj-C – How Would I Shoot From A Node To Another Node?

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, sprite-kit

So, I have a project with a cannon (currently a zappy ball) at the bottom of the screen, and little halos that spawn from up above. When they spawn, they move to a random spot on the higher portion of the screen. This, I already have with this code:

```
#import "GameScene.h"


@implementation GameScene
{
    CGPoint _centerOfScreen;

    SKEmitterNode *zappy;
    SKEmitterNode *behind;
}


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    // Scene.
    printf("Welcome to the GameScene!\n");
    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor blackColor];
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 0.0);

    // Set Initial Values.
    _centerOfScreen = CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.5, self.size.height * 0.5);


    // Zappy Ball.
    NSString *zapFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Zappy" ofType:@"sks"];
    zappy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:zapFile];
    zappy.name = @"zappy";
    zappy.position = CGPointMake(_centerOfScreen.x, 0.0);
    [self addChild:zappy];
    NSString *behindFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Behind" ofType:@"sks"];
    behind = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:behindFile];
    behind.position = zappy.position;
    [self addChild:behind];


    // Call Functions.
    SKAction *spawnHalos = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:0.8],
                                                [SKAction performSelector:@selector(spawnHalos) onTarget:self]]];
    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:spawnHalos] withKey:@"SpawnHalos"];


}


-(void)rotateNode:(SKNode *)facingNode toFaceNode:(SKNode *)facedNode {

    double angle = atan2(facedNode.position.y - facingNode.position.y, facedNode.position.x - facingNode.position.x);

    if (facingNode.zRotation < 0) {
        facingNode.zRotation = facingNode.zRotation + M_PI * 2;
    }

    [facingNode runAction:[SKAction rotateToAngle:angle duration:0]];
}


-(void)spawnHalos {
    printf("Spawn\n");

    SKSpriteNode *halo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"RedHalo"];
    halo.size = CGSizeMake(halo.size.width * 0.8, halo.size.height * 0.8);
    halo.name = @"halo";
    halo.position = CGPointMake((arc4random_uniform(self.size.width * 2.0)),
                                (arc4random_uniform(self.size.height) + self.size.height));
    [self addChild:halo];
    [halo runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake((arc4random_uniform((self.size.width * 0.7) + (self.size.width * 0.25))),
                                                 ((arc4random_uniform(self.size.height * 0.20) + (self.size.height * 0.8))))
                            duration:1.0]];

    [self rotateNode:halo toFaceNode:zappy];


    // Lessen the time between spawnings.
    SKAction *spawnHaloAction = [self actionForKey:@"SpawnHalo"];
    if (spawnHaloAction.speed < 2.3) {
        spawnHaloAction.speed += 0.01;
    }

}


-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        SKNode *touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if ([touchedNode.name  isEqual: @"halo"]) {
            // Touched a halo –– DESTROY IT!!
            printf("Remove\n");
            [touchedNode removeFromParent];
        }


    }

}


-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"halo" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
        [self rotateNode:node toFaceNode:zappy];

        // Shrink the size of the halos, gradually...
        //[node runAction:[SKAction scaleXBy:0.99 y:0.99 duration:0.0]];
    }];

}


@end
```

So, I have that all figured out. What my question is, is that I need to have the halos come on the screen, wait for about 2 seconds, and then start shooting at the cannon at the bottom of the screen. After about 2 seconds, it shoots again. It continues to shoot until it's shot (no necessary code for shooting the *halos*). I started to work on the code for that, but I could only get it that every halo shoots at the same time.

I want the timer for each halo to start when it itself appears on the screen. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks, Christian! All help is . . . helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SKAction block. I used `self` in the example below. You would replace self with your node.

```
SKAction *wait0 = [SKAction waitForDuration:2.0];
SKAction *block0 = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"shoot");
}];
[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[block0, wait0]]]];
```

Comment: This has basically answered my question exactly how I want! A little tweaking and it'll work perfectly. Thanks, Sangony! Accepted!

Comment: @ChristianKreiter - Glad to hear it. SKAction blocks are extremely useful for running independent code on nodes.